# How to recover original ctrl-p function in vim insert mode when install YouCompleteMe plugin?

Tags: vim

I've installed many plugins in my .vimrc.
If I removed the .vimrc, the ctrl-p/ctrl-n will do the completion work.(ref:  `:help completion()`.
How to check the key mapping conflict of vim plugins?
How to re-map the original function.

My sample text is t.cpp in insert mode as:
This
T<-- press ctrl-p here, it failed, but ctrl-x,ctrl-p will show This

Here are vi commands and its result:

```
:verbose imap <c-p>  # No mapping found
:unmap <c-p>         # E31: No such mapping
```

After step by step comment out plugin, I found the major problem is caused by 
YouCompleteMe plugin, it works again when I comment out YouCompleteMe.

But, why this plugin can remove the ctrl-p original function without map?
Is it possible to restore the original ctrl-p function and install the YouCompleteMe plugin?

Comment: For starters, `:verbose imap <c-p>` (similarly for `<c-n>`) to check what is redefining it.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove mappings using `unmap` command. Use

```
:unmap <c-p>
```

Then check to make sure there are no mappings using

```
:verbose imap <c-p>
```

If vim returns

> No mapping found

You're good to go